# Extracting specific substring from a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to consolidate the strings below for lack of a better term - I would like to identify all examples of "BB" and change them to "BB", same for all examples of "B" to "B" and the same for all CCC examples to make all categories uniform. Below is the list of all unique examples in the list:

```
array(['BB+', 'B-', 'BB', 'BB-', 'CCC+', 'N.A.', 'CCC', 'B+', 'B', None,
       'BB *-', 'B- *+', 'CC *-', 'B+ *-', 'BB- *-', 'NR', 'CCC-', 'BBB-',
       'B+ *+', 'BB+ *+', 'B *+', 'BB *+', 'D', 'BB+ *-', 'CCC+ *+',
       'BBB', 'C *-', 'CCC+ *-', 'BB- *+', 'CCC *+', 'FLD UNKNO',
       '(P)CCC+', '(P)B+', 'C', 'CCC- *-', 'BBB- *-'], dtype=object)
```

So for example, all 'BB+' would be changed to 'BB'

Same for examples like 'BB+ *+' would be converted to just 'BB'

I had been using

```
.str.find('BB').replace(0,'BB')
```

On the particular column of the dataframe, but the problem is all of the B+/-/flat and CCC examples are identified as -1 so I can't differentiate from there.

The ideal output would be:

BB+, BB, BB-, any iteration of those with *+, *-, (P), etc would output to BB

B+, B, B-, any iteration of those  *+, *-, (P), etc would output to B

CCC+, CCC, CCC- any iteration of those with *+, *-, (P) would output to CCC

Comment: Please [edit] your question and share the code you've tried and what the problem with that code is. You could maybe do a loop over the array and check if e.g., `"BB" in element` and then change it. See also [ask].

Comment: So, for example `BBB- *-` should become `BBB` and `(P)B+` should become `B`? Please edit your question and put there expected output.

Comment: Edited above - hopefully that's helpful. Let me know if that's not clear

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(npArr)):
  if 'BBB' in npArr[i]:
    npArr[i] = 'BBB'
  elif 'BB' in npArr[i]:
    npArr[i] = 'BB'
  elif 'B' in npArr[i]:
    npArr[i] = 'B'
  elif 'CCC' in npArr[i]:
    npArr[i] = 'CCC'
```

I had to change a couple things to make this work. Firstly, I changed the dtype of the array to `dtype=str`. I'm not sure if that's a breaking change for you, but otherwise it would require more work. Secondly, I set the array to the variable `npArr`.

Here is the output:

```
['BB' 'B' 'BB' 'BB' 'CCC' 'N.A.' 'CCC' 'B' 'B' 'None' 'BB' 'B' 'CC *-' 'B'
 'BB' 'NR' 'CCC' 'BBB' 'B' 'BB' 'B' 'BB' 'D' 'BB' 'CCC' 'BBB' 'C *-' 'CCC'
 'BB' 'CCC' 'FLD UNKNO' 'CCC' 'B' 'C' 'CCC' 'BBB']
```

Answer (score 0):

If `lst` is your list from the question, then this example changes `B`, `BB` and `CCC` values:

```py
import re

pat = re.compile(r"\b(?:B{1,2}|CCC)\b")

out = []
for item in lst:
    if not isinstance(item, str):
        out.append(item)
        continue

    m = pat.search(item)
    if m:
        out.append(m.group(0))
    else:
        out.append(item)

for a, b in zip(out, lst):
    print(b, a, sep="\t")
```

Prints:

```
BB+     BB
B-      B
BB      BB
BB-     BB
CCC+    CCC
N.A.    N.A.
CCC     CCC
B+      B
B       B
None    None
BB *-   BB
B- *+   B
CC *-   CC *-
B+ *-   B
BB- *-  BB
NR      NR
CCC-    CCC
BBB-    BBB-
B+ *+   B
BB+ *+  BB
B *+    B
BB *+   BB
D       D
BB+ *-  BB
CCC+ *+ CCC
BBB     BBB
C *-    C *-
CCC+ *- CCC
BB- *+  BB
CCC *+  CCC
FLD UNKNO       FLD UNKNO
(P)CCC+ CCC
(P)B+   B
C       C
CCC- *- CCC
BBB- *- BBB- *-
```

Comment: Apologies for the delay - thank you!